# Value is passed only to single database or condition. Confused

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables ie. y2011_2012 and y2012_2013 in my database fyproject...

Now i have created a search box with this code:

```
<form action="includes/usn_search.php" method="post">
    <input type="search" id="usn_search" name="usn_search">
</form>
```

Now i am trying to retrieve data from the two tables with this code using php:

```
//1.Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root",DB_PASS);
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());    
}

//2.Select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db("fyproject",$connection);
if(!$db_select){
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

//load
$usn = strtoupper($_POST["usn_search"]);

    if($usn == ($result1= mysql_query("SELECT usn1 OR usn2 OR usn3 OR usn4 FROM y2011_2012 WHERE usn1=\"$usn\" OR usn2=\"$usn\" OR usn3=\"$usn\" OR usn4=\"$usn\"", $connection)))
    {

        $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM y2011_2012 WHERE usn1=\"$usn\" OR usn2=\"$usn\" OR usn3=\"$usn\" OR usn4=\"$usn\"", $connection);
        if(!$result1){
                die("Database query failed: ". mysql_error());
            }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

            echo "<head><title>".$row["filename"]."</title></head>";
            echo "<body>";
                echo "<h2><center>".$row["filename"]."</center></h2>";
                echo $row["usn1"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name1"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn2"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name2"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn3"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name3"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn4"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name4"]."<br />";
                echo "<h3><center>"."Abstract"."</center></h3>"."<br />";
                echo $row["content"]."<br />";
            echo "</body>";
            }
    }

    else if($usn == ($result2= mysql_query("SELECT usn1 OR usn2 OR usn3 OR usn4 FROM y2012_2013 WHERE usn1=\"$usn\" OR usn2=\"$usn\" OR usn3=\"$usn\" OR usn4=\"$usn\"", $connection)))
    {

        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM y2012_2013 WHERE usn1=\"$usn\" OR usn2=\"$usn\" OR usn3=\"$usn\" OR usn4=\"$usn\"", $connection);
        if(!$result2){
            die("Database query failed: ". mysql_error());
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {

            echo "<head><title>".$row["filename"]."</title></head>";
            echo "<body>";
                echo "<h2><center>".$row["filename"]."</center></h2>";
                echo $row["usn1"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name1"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn2"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name2"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn3"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name3"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn4"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name4"]."<br />";
                echo "<h3><center>"."Abstract"."</center></h3>"."<br />";
                echo $row["content"]."<br />";
            echo "</body>";
        }
    }

    else {
        echo "Not found!";
    }
```

Now whenever i try to input the USN that is present in the first table, i get the desired output i want seamlessly.. but suppose if i put the value present in the second table i am getting a blank page.. No error page from php or the last echo which says "Not found".. I guess the value doesnt pass to the second else if condition but i dunno why?? Please help

Comment: is y2011_2012 and y2012_2013 table or database ?

Comment: @akhil Extremely sorry.. Those are the tables

Comment: @RaHuL- Can i see your table structure along with some values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand how the if clause works in your code. In your if clause, you are comparing a variable to an associative array which will never be the same. So technically, it shouldn't work. I have modified your code a bit, can you try running this

```
<?php
//1.Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root",DB_PASS);
if(!$connection){
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());    
}

//2.Select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db("fyproject",$connection);
if(!$db_select){
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

//load
$usn = strtoupper(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["usn_search"]));

    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM y2011_2012 WHERE usn1=\"$usn\" OR usn2=\"$usn\" OR usn3=\"$usn\" OR usn4=\"$usn\"", $connection);
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM y2012_2013 WHERE usn1=\"$usn\" OR usn2=\"$usn\" OR usn3=\"$usn\" OR usn4=\"$usn\"", $connection);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
            echo "<head><title>".$row["filename"]."</title></head>";
            echo "<body>";
                echo "<h2><center>".$row["filename"]."</center></h2>";
                echo $row["usn1"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name1"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn2"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name2"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn3"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name3"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn4"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name4"]."<br />";
                echo "<h3><center>"."Abstract"."</center></h3>"."<br />";
                echo $row["content"]."<br />";
            echo "</body>";
            }
    }
    else if(mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo "<head><title>".$row["filename"]."</title></head>";
            echo "<body>";
                echo "<h2><center>".$row["filename"]."</center></h2>";
                echo $row["usn1"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name1"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn2"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name2"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn3"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name3"]."<br />";
                echo $row["usn4"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name4"]."<br />";
                echo "<h3><center>"."Abstract"."</center></h3>"."<br />";
                echo $row["content"]."<br />";
            echo "</body>";
        }
    }else {
        echo "Not found!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Fabulous it worked!!! I've accepted your answer and considered useful.. Thank you very much.. I'll try to understand what you actually did.. I'm new to php and mysql